# MySQL varaible innodb_file_per_table in production activate

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5

I have a MySQL-Server 5.5  with around 5.000.000 records in each table.

Now i want to activate the variable "innodb_file_per_table = 1".

Is this possible?
Is there any risk to do that?

The Reason is for activating the option, is to optimize performance.

Thanks and Regards
Chris

Comment: There is likely to be no performance gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. All advantages and possible disadvantages are mentioned in official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)
Also you should be aware that only new tables will be created in separated tablespace or you can rebuild any existing table to moved from shared tablespace.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. For rebuild the existing table i just executed the below statment for each table is that correct? or any other steps needed?

ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: alter is enough. be aware if you are going to use ALTER it will lock your table so you should schedule downtime or you can go with any OSC tools: percona, facebook, open-ark and so on

Comment: Ok, but after the statement is executed the table would be unlock automatically?

Comment: yes, it will be unlocked, btw. if answer help you could mark it as accepted to help other people to understand that it would solve the issue

Comment: @hugi86 - You have accepted this answer, but there is a very important point about the size of `ibdata1` in the answer from @Michael-sqlbot.  Recouping that space will be more painful.

Answer (score 1):

`innodb_file_per_table` is a dynamic variable -- changing it can safely be done without even restarting the server... but the big caveat is that you can never reclaim the disk space consumed by the `ibdata` file.

Tables that are rebuilt with the setting enabled will have their own tablespace files, but `ibdata1` cannot be shrunk without a dump, followed by removal of `ibdata1` and reinitialization of the server, and then a reload of all the data.

"Performance" is not necessarily a valid reason to change the setting on a working server.

Comment: Means? ibdata file will have still the same size?

Comment: Correct. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-resize-system-tablespace.html